# Python reduce inside a filter

Tags: python, lambda, sympy

I have a list with M tuples of N coordinates each (N-dimensional).
each coordinate is a sympy expression, and I want to take only real points (all coordinates are real).

I wrote the following code:

```
points = filter(lambda p: reduce(
    lambda c1, c2: c1.is_real and c2.is_real, p), points)
```

And it doesn't work (`NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined`). I obviously don't fully understand how these types of expressions work, but I want something equivalent to:

```
remove_points = []
for point in points:
    for coordinate in point:
        if not coordinate.is_real:
            remove_points.append(point)
            break
for point in remove_points:
    points.remove(point)
```

which worked for me. Can anyone point to where I went wrong and how should it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Python version do you use? `reduce` got removed in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins).

Don't use `list` for `remove_points`, use `set` instead, it will be faster.

And what is wrong with the second approach if it works? But maybe you would want to consider the following, too:

```
result = [point for point in points if all(coordinate.is_real for coordinate in point)]
```

Comment: I do use Python3, I moved recently from Python2 and wasn't aware of the change. I wish to replace the 2nd approach with a more elegant one